# AVML memory capture with Azure Commandline

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-sas

I am trying to capture the memory of a Linux VM with [AVML](https://github.com/microsoft/avml#capturing-a-memory-image-of-an-azure-vm-using-vm-extensions), with Azure CLI remotely.

Basically, I generated a SAS-URL with...

```
az storage container generate-sas \
    --account-name <storage-account> \
    --name <container> \
    --permissions acdlrw \
    --expiry <date-time> \
    --auth-mode login \
    --as-user
```

...and executed the following command:

```
az vm extension set -g <resource-group> --vm-name <vm-name> --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions -n customScript --settings config.json
```

... and I got the following output:

(`config.json` is in the output as well. See `settings: {...}`)

```
{
  "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
  "enableAutomaticUpgrade": null,
  "forceUpdateTag": null,
  "id": "/subscriptions/<...>/customScript",
  "instanceView": null,
  "location": "<geo-location>",
  "name": "customScript",
  "protectedSettings": null,
  "protectedSettingsFromKeyVault": null,
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
  "resourceGroup": "<resource-group>",
  "settings": {
    "commandToExecute": "./avml --compress --sas-url <sas-url>",
    "fileUris": [
      "https://github.com/microsoft/avml/releases/download/v0.6.0/avml"
    ]
  },
  "suppressFailures": null,
  "tags": null,
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "typeHandlerVersion": "2.1",
  "typePropertiesType": "customScript"
}
```

... but the container associated with this SAS URL is empty. Is there anything wrong with my commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, and the answer is that...

You need `\"\"` around `<sas-url>`.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT I can only accept my own answer tomorrow.